# Git Fetch changes confusion

Tags: git

I have a scenario. I have a remote repo with two branches: master and branchA. Two programmers are working on a local branchA and push this to the remote branchA.

I want to know the command to get the changes that the other programmer push to the remote branchA to my local branchA.
I am not sure which one is the right one, fetch, merge or pull ? I didn't manage to find a command to fetch/pull/merge from a specific remote branch and not from the remote/master.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following commands:

```
# Change to your local branchA
git checkout branchA

# Pull changes from origin/branchA
git pull origin branchA
```

Comment: I would add to this a bit - if your goal is simply to make sure you have copies of their commits in your repository, then a simple `git fetch` will suffice, and leave the state of the remote's `branchA` in e.g. `origin/branchA` (although it doesn't touch your current local `branchA`). Later, if you want to review their changes, `git checkout branchA; git merge origin/branchA` will update your local branch so you can do your review. The above solution works fine if you want to look at it right away, though.